# Foreign Key with Django REST Serializers

Tags: python, django, api, rest

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the Foreign key relationship to work with my Django REST api.

**I have a model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator



# Create your models here.
class Hero(models.Model):
  alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
  alias = models.CharField(max_length=60)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class SideKick(models.Model):
  alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
  hero = models.ForeignKey(Hero, related_name='sidekicks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  sideKick_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, validators=[alphanumeric])

  def __str__(self):
    return self.sideKick_name
```

**Serializers**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Hero, SideKick

class HeroSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  sidekicks = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='title')

  class Meta:
    model = Hero
    fields = ('name', 'alias', 'sidekicks')

class SideKickSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  sideKick_name = HeroSerializer()
  
  class Meta:
    model = SideKick
    fields = ('sideKick_name')
```

Here is what the api webpage looks like

[image]

I'm fairly new to this and was wondering how I can get the option to select a `Hero` to create a sidekick through the API webpage.

every time i create a hero the sidekick field is blank.

Any help would be apperciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this :

```
class HeroSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  sidekicks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ('name', 'alias', 'sidekicks')

    def get_sidekicks(self, obj):
        sidekicks = []
        SideKick_objects = SideKick.objects.all()
        for f in SideKick_objects:
            features.append({"alphanumeric": f.alphanumeric, "hero": f.hero, "sideKick_name": f.sideKick_name})
        return sidekicks
```

If you get any error for "sidekicks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()"
 try using : "serializers.ModelSerializer" instead "serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer"